# React native - Error: Hooks can only be called inside of a function component

Tags: react-native, react-hooks, components, hook

I have the following problem in my component "SubmitButton" I want to execute a custom hook by clicking on the button. This hook is called "useLogin".

But currently I always get the following error message: "Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component."

Can anyone tell me where my error is or what I am not understanding correctly?

SubmitButton Code:

```
import React from "react";
import { View, Text, TouchableOpacity, StyleSheet } from "react-native";
import useLogin from "../../../../app/hooks/useLogin";

import { useSelector } from "react-redux";

const SubmitButton = () => {

  const email = useSelector((state) => state.login.email);
  const password = useSelector((state) => state.login.password);

  return (
    <View>
      <TouchableOpacity
        style={styles.button}
        onPress={() => useLogin({ email, password })}
      >
        <Text style={styles.text}>Anmelden</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    </View>
  );
};
```

useLogin Code:

```
import api from "../api/config";
import { useEffect } from "react";
import { useDispatch } from "react-redux";
import * as SecureStore from "expo-secure-store";
import { setJwtToken } from "../redux/features/auth/loginSlice";

export default function useLogin ({email, password}) {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  useEffect(() => {
    login({email, password});
  }, []);  

  const login = async ({ email, password }) => {
    try {
      const response = await api.post("/users/login", { email, password });
      if (response.status === 200) {
        dispatch(setJwtToken(response.data.token));
        await SecureStore.setItemAsync("jwtToken", response.data.token);
      }
    }
    catch(e) {
      console.log(e);
    }
  };
}
```

Comment: create an async function within SubmitButton Code and then add the login try catch within it. Call the function on submit

Answer (score 2):

you need to pass useLogin() to a variable ( like const dispatch = useDispatch() ) then use the variable like a function just like dispatch().

```
import React from "react";
import { View, Text, TouchableOpacity, StyleSheet } from "react-native";
import useLogin from "../../../../app/hooks/useLogin";

import { useSelector } from "react-redux";

const SubmitButton = () => {

  const email = useSelector((state) => state.login.email);
  const password = useSelector((state) => state.login.password);

  const loginHook = useLogin();

  return (
    <View>
      <TouchableOpacity
        style={styles.button}
        onPress={() => loginHook({ email, password })}
      >
        <Text style={styles.text}>Anmelden</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    </View>
  );
};
```

Comment: Hi Mohammad, thanks for your idea. However this sadly still leads to the same error as before.